# Threading. Keeps using the same info (variable while running)

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I developed a GUI in JAVA that after doing a few actions like writing to excel sends an email to a client with an attached file but sending email takes about 5 sec and sometimes it needs to send 100 emails in a row but i don´t won´t the user to wait for the emails to be sent because it is not important to him. 
So i tried creating a thread that sends the email. Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<numEmail;i++){
                info=getSomething(i);
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                sendEmail(info);
            System.out.println("Email sent");
            }
        }.start();
}
```

Although i create new Thread  every email comes with the info of the first email instead of every email with different info.

I'm a rookie java programmer and know very little of threading. I just need to not freeze the GUI for sending email. I never now the amont of emails to send but they all have different information to send.

Answer (score 2):

you have missed a couple of curly braces. the thread is always running with the last value of i.

```
for(int i=0; i<numEmail;i++){
info=getSomething(i);
        new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                sendEmail(info);
            System.out.println("Email sent");
            }
        }.start();
}
```

Comment: I didn´t added them here but that is not the problem. Corrected it.

Comment: what is in the getsomething method

Comment: it retrieves an object from a list that contains an int[] , String, String that are used to make a JSON file. But i don´t think that is the issue. for some reason although i use new Thread it keeps using the 1st